# How should NgxsModule.forRoot()/NgxsModule.forFeature() be used?

Tags: angular, ngxs

I have a main `app.module.ts` in my project, as well as several modules for different features, such as `archive.module.ts`. I use local storage to restore certain settings on page refresh, so I also use NgxsStoragePluginModule for it.

And I am confused in which of the modules I should add these lines:

```
imports: [
NgxsModule.forRoot([ArchiveState]),
  NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
       key: [ArchiveState]
  }),
]
```

In the main `app.module.ts` or in the module for the `archive.module.ts` feature?

Should I use `NgxsModule.forFeature([ArchiveState])` in one of these modules?

Comment: put it in common or shared modules if you are using from every module
Or only in that module where u want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of `NgxsModule.forRoot` should be in your `app.module.ts` (your module on the root of the application). Note that this is required even if you have no root state.

The `NgxsModule.forFeature` can be used to create "child" states that are lazily created when a feature is loaded. Normally contains a slice of the state that is appended to the global state. In your example, you should be added to your `archive.module.ts`.

For the `NgxsStoragePluginModule`, this module does not currently (@ngxs/storage-plugin@3.7.6) support the `forFeature` option. Therefore, you need to add this also in your root module, in this case `app.module.ts`.

In summary you'd have this:

```js
// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    NgxsModule.forRoot([]),
    NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
      key: [ArchiveState]
    }),
  ],
})

// archive.module.ts
@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    NgxsModule.forFeature([ArchiveState]),
  ],
})
```

It is not an ideal situation since you end up breaking the separation of concern by having to import the `ArchiveState` in your root module anyhow. This has been a feature request for the `LocalStoragePlugin` for a while. See the feature request here: https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/850.

Comment: There is no any progress since 2019 sadly.

Comment: @withoutOne You are more than welcome to contribute to our open source library :)